# Simple friendship in Parse

Tags: parse-platform

I have asked this question in parse.com google group, but didn't get an answer. So technically this is an x-post.

I want to make a simple friendship class in parse between two users(not parse users, I have a profile table with user objects in it). Since there is no examples in JS sdk guide of parse, I am just trying to make something that works. So I've decided to make a friendship class in parse, and have pointer for each friendship:

> *pointer* **user1**      *pointer* **user2**

But with this method I've encountered some issues like when trying to get a persons friendlist I need to make 2 different queries, also when adding a friendship need to double check to avoid duplicating etc.

So what I am trying to achieve is a simple friendship class, where I can easily determine if 2 users are friends, get users friendlist, avoid duplicating in the db.

Comment: `determine if 2 users are friends, get users friendlist, avoid duplicating in the db.` Can you explain more on this? If you want to get results from each of these stuffs, there's no way, unless they are conditions to your query that leads to a list of objects. What does `get users friendlist` means?

Comment: `get users friendList` means to retrieve all friends of a user, the difficulty here is that userObejct whose friendlist I want to get could be contained in either **user1** or **user2** field. 

Also, all the other things I said I was trying to achieve, were about different methods, not a single query. Overall I wanted to know what is the best way to handle friendship in parse. 

I have already solved this issue by adding friendlist array to the profile table(for each user), so there is nothing urgent about this question, I just want to learn better practices of parse.